# Target Specific Javascript Object Literal fields and array with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant seem to get this to work. Im trying to do two things

A). Get the following code to show up correctly. The first element is show 'undefined

```
<ul>
<li>Button
<ul>
 <li>x:1</li>
 <li>y:2</li>
 <li>width:3</li>
 <li>height:4</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var data = {
    "Controls": [{
            "Button":[{ "x": "1","y": "2","width": "3","height": "4" }],

            "Image":[{"x": "5","y": "6","width": "7","height": "8"}],

            "TextField":[{"x": "9","y": "10","width": "11","height": "12"}]
        }]
}

var str = '<ul>';
$.each(data.Controls, function(k, v) {
    str += '<li>' + k[0] + '</li><ul>';
    for(var kk in v.Button[0]){
        str += '<li>' + kk + ':' + v.Button[0][kk] + '</li>';
    }
    str += '</ul>';
});
str += '</ul>';
$('div').append(str);
})
```

And

B). trying to display a list(separate list from above) of just the fields. like this:

```
<li>Button</li>
<li>Image</li>
<li>TextField</li>
```

I think that the answer to the second lies in the first, but I cannot seem to get the targeting right.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R2c4k/2/)**

To get the first list:

```
var str = '<ul>';
var target = "Button";

str += '<li>' + target + '<ul>';
$.each(data.Controls[0][target][0], function(kk, vv){
    str += '<li>' + kk + ':' + vv + '</li>';
});
str += '</ul></li>';

str += '</ul>';
```

To get the second list:

```
var str = '<ul>';
$.each(data.Controls[0], function(k,v) {
    str += '<li>' + k + '</li>';
});
str += '</ul>';
```

To target them by index, so `Button` is `0`:

```
var str = '<ul>';
var target = 0;
var count = 0;

$.each(data.Controls[0], function(k,v) {
    if(count == target)
    {
        str += '<li>' + k + '<ul>';

        $.each(v[0], function(kk, vv){
            str += '<li>' + kk + ':' + vv + '</li>';
        });
        str += '</ul></li>';
        return false; // <-- break because we got what we wanted
    }
    count++;
});

str += '</ul>';
```

Comment: I just tried it but returns: 

    0
        Button:[object Object]
        Image:[object Object]
        TextField:[object Object]

Comment: The second one works great. The first one returns the entire set of lists and sublists. I would like to target just one at a time. My example targeted Button.  Thanks a bunch

Comment: Updated to target just one, defined by `var target = "Button"`.

Comment: is it possible you can provide a solutions that Targets based on Index number vs a name ie. 'Button' would be Index [0].

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this has nothing to do with JSON.  JSON is a string-serialization format. What you have here is an object literal.

Second, I have no idea why you are wrapping all your object definitions inside Controls, with arrays, seems like a lot of extra hassle. You are also doing things in a very non-jQuery way.

You could try something like this:

```
var data = {
    "Controls": {
            "Button":{ "x": "1","y": "2","width": "3","height": "4" },

            "Image":{"x": "5","y": "6","width": "7","height": "8"},

            "TextField":{"x": "9","y": "10","width": "11","height": "12"}
        }
}

$('div').append('<ul id="outer_ul">');
$.each(data.Controls, function(key, value) {
    $('#outer_ul').append('<li>' + key + '</li>', '<ul id="' + key +'">');
    $('#field_list').append('<li>' + key + '</li>');
    $.each(value, function(key2, value2) {
        $('#' + key).append('<li>' + key2 + ':' + value2 + '</li>');
    }
}
```

This code populates both you `div` as well as a `ul` with the id of `field_list` which would represent the container into which you want to put the second list (so adjust this code according the the proper jQuery selector you want to use.